# evento focusout no funciona con input dinamico en ASP

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

Estoy dibujando un input de forma dinámica en una tabla con

```
document.getElementById('agregaDevolucion').innerHTML = 
    "Devolución:<input type='text' name='txtDeposito' id='txtDeposito'/>";
```

y ese mismo input hace una búsqueda a una BD a través de `AJAX` con el evento `focusout` del input, con el código siguiente

```
$('#txtDeposito').focusout(function(){
    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
    var solicitud = $('#idce').val();
    var devolucion = $('#txtDeposito').val();
    alert(devolucion);
    $.post("buscaSolicitud.asp", { solicitud : solicitud, devolucion : devolucion},
    function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
        var cadena = data.toString();
        console.log(data);
        if(cadena=="OK"){
            $('#btnEnvia').show();
            $('#error').text("Correcto").css({"color":"green"});;
        }else{
            $('#btnEnvia').hide();
            $('#error').text("El número de devolución no coincide con la solicitud").css({"color":"red"});
        }
    });
});
```

Pero el problema que tengo es que el input que dibujo no lanza el evento `focusout` ya que al probar mi aplicacion no hace nada, antes de hacer dinamico el input estaba estatico y si funcionaba, no entiendo por que no hace nada

Comment: Hola lvxn, ¿que versión de jQuery estás usando? ¿Todo el código que has puesto lo ejecutas en el DocumentReady?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar **addEventListener**, para no depender de **jquery**. Mira en JSBIN como solucionaría yo el problema: http://jsbin.com/ciwaro/edit?html,js,console,output

El código me quedó así:

```
// Agrega el objeto dinamico
document.getElementById('agregaDevolucion').innerHTML = 
    "Devolución:<input type='text' name='txtDeposito' id='txtDeposito'/>";

// Hago referencia al objeto dinámico
var txtDeposito = document.getElementById('txtDeposito');

// Agrego el listener focusout
txtDeposito.addEventListener('focusout', function() {
  console.log("entro");
});
```

También deberías analizar que existe el evento **onblur** que es muy parecido al **focusout**, el código para agregar el evento sigue siendo igual, solamente cambia un parámetro al llamar al **addEventListener**.

```
// Agrego el listener blur
txtDeposito.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  console.log("entro");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer uso del método [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) de jQuery que permite asociar eventos a un elemento y que funciona a partir de jQuery 1.7. Pero no quieres hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$("selector").on("evento", function() { ... });
```

Sino [hacerlo de manera delegada](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), es decir: el evento no se asocia directamente a un elemento, sino que se delega en un ancestro se asociará al elemento cuando sea creado. El formato para los eventos delegados es un poco diferente:

```
$("ancestro").on("evento", "selector", function() { ... });
```

Cuando haces eso, estás asociando el evento de manera delegada. Lo que estás haciendo es que cuando se cree el elemento especificado por "selector" dentro del elemento especificado en "ancestro" se le asignará la función al evento dado. En tu caso particular, podrías hacerlo así:

```
$("body").on("focusout", "#txtDeposito", function() {

    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
    var solicitud = $('#idce').val();
    var devolucion = $('#txtDeposito').val();
    alert(devolucion);
    $.post("buscaSolicitud.asp", { solicitud : solicitud, devolucion : devolucion},
    function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
        var cadena = data.toString();
        console.log(data);
        if(cadena=="OK"){
            $('#btnEnvia').show();
            $('#error').text("Correcto").css({"color":"green"});;
        }else{
            $('#btnEnvia').hide();
            $('#error').text("El número de devolución no coincide con la solicitud").css({"color":"red"});
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa el `.on()` de jquery para adjuntar dinamicamente el evento

```
$('#txtDeposito')on("focusout", function(){ ....
```

[jquery on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Para crear dinamicamente el input usa

```
$('#agregaDevolucion').html("Devolución:<input type='text' name='txtDeposito' id='txtDeposito'/>");
```

[jquery html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: no tampoco funciono

Comment: edite el ejemplo, valida si creando el html usando jquery aplica el evento

Answer (score 1):

Crea el input dinámicamente y crea la función que ejecutará el evento `onfocusout`, y al crear el input lo agregas de inmediato, así:

```
document.getElementById("agregaDevolucion").innerHTML = "Devolución:<input type='text' name='txtDeposito' onfocusout='myFunction(this);' id='txtDeposito'/>";
```

Así, al momento de crear el input quedará enlazado inmediatamente con el evento `onfocusout`, y tú función debería quedar así:

```
function myFunction(input) {
        input.value = input.value.toUpperCase();
        var solicitud = $('#idce').val();
        //alert(solicitud);
        var devolucion = $('#txtDeposito').val();
        alert(devolucion);
        //....................
}
```

Yo lo probé y si me lanzo el evento.