# Ayuda con Javascript & HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un formulario creado a base de `append()` de JavaScript como resultado de lo obtenido en AJAX para recibir y manipular Array de PHP convertido a JSON. También tengo un `on` para capturar el formulario cuando este haga `submit()`, pero ahí está el problema, el formulario no es capturado, y el `submit` se realiza de forma normal, el `preventDefault()` no funciona.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var array_vehiculos = new Array();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'data/load_veh.php',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            array_vehiculos = JSON.parse(data);
            $.each(array_vehiculos,function(index,val){
                $(".content.c-veh").append(
                    '<div class="sub-item">'+
                        '<form method="POST" id="veh">'+
                            '<input type="hidden" name="val-veh" value="'+val['matricula_veh']+'">'+
                            '<button type="submit" class="nothing">'+
                                '<img src="img/taxi/taxi.png" class="imgfit">'+
                            '</button>'+
                        '</form>'+
                    '</div>'
                );
            });
        }
    });
    $("#veh").on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefult();
        alert("Hola");
    });
});
```

**Edición**

- Tuve un error en escribir preventDefault(), había escrito preventDefult().

Comment: Esta pregunta es un duplicado de (al menos) una pregunta diferente. Deja que la encuentre y la enlace.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [jquery DataTables no permite abrir modal dialog despues de 10 filas](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/9471/jquery-datatables-no-permite-abrir-modal-dialog-despues-de-10-filas). Sé que a primera vista no parece un duplicado, pero creeme, lo es. El problema es el mismo: asociar controladores de eventos a un elemento antes de que dicho elemento se cree en el DOM.

Comment: No estoy trabjando DataTables.

Comment: Lee la edición del comentario. Si quieres te pongo una respuesta adaptada a tu caso particular, pero se debería poder abstraer el problema a lo mismo.

Comment: Y bien, cuál podría ser la solución?

Comment: Gracias a tu reporte, ahora tengo otra pregunta negativa, cuando en la pregunta usen las mismas funciones que en la mía, entonces sí sería duplicado. Mi pregunta no es duplicada. Qué mierda.

Comment: Hola máxima. Los votos negativos nada tienen que ver con el reporte. Por favor mantengamos el respecto mutuo en todo momento. Si crees que no es un duplicado edita tu pregunta explicando el por qué. Un saludo.

Comment: Pero es que hombre, en lo que citó Montoro, ni siquiera usan mis mismas funciones como append(), son preguntas diferentes. Por eso me enoja los puntos negativos en base al "duplicado" afirmado por Montoro. No comprendo, probablemente la finalidad sea similar a mi pregunta, pero no es igual de todos modos.

Comment: Des de mi punto de vista se trata de un duplicado por qué las respuestas posibles ya existen en otras preguntas. Eso no significa que tu pregunta sea mala, que no lo es, y por eso yo te he dado un +1. Aunque tu planteamiento sea distinto la respuesta a tu pregunta es genérica, si se marca como duplicado eso es muy útil para futuros usuarios. Marcar duplicado no es eliminar mi despreciar tu pregunta, a veces le da más valor.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz Yo también te di un +1, la pregunta en sí no es mala. No me imaginaba que te iban a votar negativo.

Comment: +1, es buena la pregunta y el voto negativo no tiene que ver con el reporte. No te preocupes por eso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te pongo en un comentario esto es un duplicado de otras preguntas ya existentes en StackOverflow en Español (aquí dejo [1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8532/evento-focusout-no-funciona-con-input-dinamico-en-asp/), [2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/9471/jquery-datatables-no-permite-abrir-modal-dialog-despues-de-10-filas), y [3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/19934/ocupar-solicitudes-ajax-en-mas-de-un-select-clonado-laravel-5/) ejemplos, todos parecen completamente diferentes, pero todos tienen el mismo problema de raíz)

El problema es que se está asociando el controlador del evento `submit` a un elemento antes de que dicho elemento se cree en el DOM. Deberían asociarse los eventos de forma delegada.

Donde haces esto:

```
$("#veh").on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Hola");
});
```

Deberías estar haciendo esto otro usando [delegación de eventos](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

```
$("body").on('submit', "#veh", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Hola");
});
```

Pero aún así podrás encontrarte con otro problema. Tal y como está hora mismo el código, parece que podría darse el caso de hubiese IDs duplicados, lo cual puede volver un poco loco a jQuery. Sería mejor que en lugar de ponerles a todos el ID `veh`, se lo pusieras como clase.

Comment: Wow, primera vez que veo un uso del selector en el **on**

Comment: Te puse un enlace a la documentación oficial de jQuery a la sección donde se explican los eventos delegados y por qué ese selector en el `on`. Pero, como pongo en la edición, puedes seguir teniendo problemas con IDs duplicados.

Comment: Pero tengo un detalle adicional, y es que en el body no estará el formulario, hay varios divs primero antes de llegar al form.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz eso no importa. Mientras esos `div` estén en el `body` no importa. Pero si quieres hacerlo más eficiente, podrías hacer algo como `$(".c-veh").on('submit', "#veh", function(event) { ... }`

Comment: Encontré la solución, a un problema adicional, Jajajaja pos me mato, mira en el preventDefault()... 'preventDefult()' Jajajaja.

Comment: A mí también se me pasó :$

Comment: Jajajaja gracias hombre, como siempre,

Comment: El legendario Montaro, volvió a salvarme :v